# CSS How to keep a hovered element in place

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking to get my highlighter (blue bar) to stay on the element that is clicked on. I want to keep the hover animation but also include the option to have it stay on the `<div>` the user clicks. Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Pen: https://codepen.io/chriskaram/pen/eGXrOp

```
<div class="demo">
<div class="demo__content">
    <h2 class="demo__heading">Assessment</h2>
    <div class="demo__elems">
        <div class="demo__elem demo__elem-1">Novice Assessment</div>
        <div class="demo__elem demo__elem-2">Apprentice Assessment</div>
        <div class="demo__elem demo__elem-3">Advanced Assessment</div>
        <span class="demo__hover demo__hover-1"></span>
        <span class="demo__hover demo__hover-2"></span>
        <span class="demo__hover demo__hover-3"></span>
        <div class="demo__highlighter">
            <div class="demo__elems">
                <div class="demo__elem">Novice Assessment</div>
                <div class="demo__elem">Apprentice Assessment</div>
                <div class="demo__elem">Advanced Assessment</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="demo__examples">
            <div class="demo__examples-nb">
                <div class="nb-inner">
                    <div class="example example-adv">
                        <div class="example-adv">
                            <div class="example-adv__top">
                                <div class="example-adv__top-search"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="example-adv__mid"></div>
                            <div class="example-adv__line"></div>
                            <div class="example-adv__line long"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="example example-web">
                        <div class="example-web__top"></div>
                        <div class="example-web__left"></div>
                        <div class="example-web__right">
                            <div class="example-web__right-line"></div>
                            <div class="example-web__right-line"></div>
                            <div class="example-web__right-line"></div>
                            <div class="example-web__right-line"></div>
                            <div class="example-web__right-line"></div>
                            <div class="example-web__right-line"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="example example-both">
                        <div class="example-both__half example-both__left">
                            <div class="example-both__left-top"></div>
                            <div class="example-both__left-mid"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="example-both__half example-both__right">
                            <div class="example-both__right-top"></div>
                            <div class="example-both__right-mid"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please include relevant code in the question itself. Is all the code you have provided relevant to the question at hand, e.g. are all those empty `div` tags relevant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example, I just focused on `demo__element-3`.

Check this link: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GMbYdz

These are the modifications to be made:

**CSS:**

Add `.active` to all `demo__hover-3:hover` styles(in css).
 *(ie, add `.demo__hover-3.active` to `.demo__hover-3:hover`)*

**Element:**

Add class
   `active` to `demo__hover` elements.
*(in this case, it become
   `<span class="demo__hover demo__hover-3 active"></span>`)*

**Jquery:**

Add jquery to add `active` to element if user clicks it.

Comment: Please check now. I didn't add any jquery function to add `active` class to the element when user click it.

Comment: That work perfectly. I had to include a DOM content loader to get it to work on my website. But regardless it works flawlessly, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just like the bootstrap manu when you click one option it will add a class 'active' to element `<li>`